# Display modal popup without page loading using asp.net and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

As per **Jitendra Tiwari** suggestion i have changed my code and it works fine, it displaying popup but parallely page is loading after loading page popup will not display Here is the code i have changed 
 `<obout:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="duplicate">
    <Template>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkbtnDuplicate" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtnDuplicate_Click" AlternateText="Duplicate"                                    CssClass='<%#Container.DataItem["schedule1"]%>' OnClientClick="OpenPopup();"></asp:ImageButton>
    </Template>
</obout:GridTemplate>`
and in dialog box have to display message that code is
 `<div>
            <div id="popupdiv" title="Basic modal dialog"  class="dialog">
                Are you sure you want ready to duplicate?
            <div class="footer" style="padding: 8px;">
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Proceed" CssClass="yes" OnClick="btnOkay_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="no" OnClick="btnCancel1_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnOkay" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="yes hide" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="no hide" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
Jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {

         $("#popupdiv").dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
                title: "Dualistic e-Filing",
                width: 430,
                height: 250,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });              
     })
     function OpenPopup() {
         $("#popupdiv").dialog("open");
         return false;
     }
</script>
```

my back-end code is

```
 protected void lnkbtnDuplicate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            Hashtable selectedRec = (Hashtable)ogridForms.SelectedRecords[0];
            Session["formkey_temp"] = Convert.ToString(selectedRec["form_key"].ToString());
            Session["bussiness_temp"] = Convert.ToString(selectedRec["business_key"]);
            Session["filling_temp"] = Convert.ToString(selectedRec["filing_type"]).ToUpper();
        }
        catch { }
    }
    protected void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BAL_F2290 objFormKeys = new BAL_F2290();
            var s = objFormKeys.Duplicate(Session["formkey_temp"].ToString());
            Session["FORM_KEY"] = Convert.ToString(s);
            Session["BUSINESS_KEY"] = Convert.ToString(Session["bussiness_temp"]);
            Session["FILING_TYPE"] = Convert.ToString(Session["filling_temp"]).ToUpper();
            Response.Redirect("TaxPeriod.aspx?dup=1");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string a = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    protected void btnCancel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Session["formkey_temp"] = null;
        Session["bussiness_temp"] = null;
        Session["filling_temp"] = null;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the error code? The current question doesn't have it attached

Comment: have you include required js files (jquery and jquery ui)??

Answer (score 1):

You should try with `OnClientClick` event.

Try this solution

```
<obout:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="duplicate">
    <Template>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkbtnDuplicate" runat="server"
            OnClick="lnkbtnDuplicate_Click" AlternateText="Duplicate"
            CssClass='<%#Container.DataItem["schedule1"]%>' OnClientClick="return OpenPopup();">   
        </asp:ImageButton>
    </Template>
</obout:GridTemplate>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 // Create your dialog one time when page ready
 $(function () {         
        $("#popupdiv").dialog({
            autoOpen:false, 
            title: "jQuery Popup from Server Side",
            width: 430,
            height: 250,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });                    
 });
 // Open using this function
 function OpenPopup() {
     $("#popupdiv").dialog("open");
     return false;
 }
</script>
```

**Insert grid template inside update panel**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>                    
            <obout:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="duplicate">
               <Template>
                  <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkbtnDuplicate" runat="server"
                    OnClick="lnkbtnDuplicate_Click" AlternateText="Duplicate"
                    CssClass='<%#Container.DataItem["schedule1"]%>'    OnClientClick="OpenPopup();">   
                  </asp:ImageButton>
              </Template>
           </obout:GridTemplate>
        </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks it is working..........but one more problem is there. When i click on Duplicate imagebutton it will display popup and parallel page will loading and after loading popup will not display

Comment: This is backend code ' Hashtable selectedRec = (Hashtable)ogridForms.SelectedRecords[0];
                Session["formkey_temp"] = Convert.ToString(selectedRec["form_key"].ToString());
                Session["bussiness_temp"] = Convert.ToString(selectedRec["business_key"]);
                Session["filling_temp"] = Convert.ToString(selectedRec["filing_type"]).ToUpper();'

Comment: did you done anything in back-end using this button? If Yes, then grid should be in update panel. Else remove `OnClick="lnkbtnDuplicate_Click" ` from image button.

Comment: however `return false` will stop calling back-end functionality and it will work for me.

Comment: check my updated code **Insert grid template inside update panel**

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id*=btnPopup]").live("click", function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
 <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
This is a simple popup
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnPopup" runat="server" Text="Show Popup" />
```

Comment: But Id should be within <obout:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="duplicate">
    <Template> </Template>
</obout:GridTemplate>     tags because i am bringing data from database so.......

Comment: Refer this link  http://www.obout.com/obout.ajax.ui/htmleditor/examples/MSACT_modalPopup.aspx